# messaging.requestPermission is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

trying to send push notification to app but i need permission from user for that but getting this error that messaging.requestPermission is not a function  ,
here is my code for push notification.js file

```js
import * as  firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
export const  initializeFirebase = () => {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "pushnotification-9b180",
    storageBucket: "pushnotification-9b180.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "878043563283",
    appId: "1:878043563283:web:c2a44f3c8b02ad8a17c6e6",
    measurementId: "G-GMWQKL94ZD"
  });
}
 
export const askForPermissionToReceiveNotifications = async () => {
    try {
      const messaging = getMessaging();

      await messaging.requestPermission();
      const token = await messaging.getToken();
      console.log('Your token is:', token);
      
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Here is the screenshot of errors

[image: erros]

Comment: Which version of Firebase are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using react-native or react?

but in react-native way you need add this line

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```

you don´t need

```
const messaging = getMessaging();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as  firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
export const  initializeFirebase = () => {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "pushnotification-9b180",
    storageBucket: "pushnotification-9b180.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "878043563283",
    appId: "1:878043563283:web:c2a44f3c8b02ad8a17c6e6",
    measurementId: "G-GMWQKL94ZD"
  });
}
 
export const askForPermissionToReceiveNotifications = async () => {
    try {
      const messaging = getMessaging();

      await messaging.requestPermission();
      const token = await messaging.getToken();
      console.log('Your token is:', token);
      
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).